# Limit max parallelism for a single RDD without decreasing the number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to limit the max number of concurrent tasks at the RDD level without changing the actual number of partitions? The use case is to not overwhelm a database with too many concurrent connections without reducing the number of partitions. Reducing the number of partitions causes each partition to become larger and eventually unmanageable.

Comment: you should provide lesser number of executor to your spark-job..

Comment: @rogue-one That would limit the resources available for the rest of the stages in the job, which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-posting this as an "answer" because I think it may be the least-dirty hack that might get the behavior you want:

Use a `mapPartitions(...)` call, and at the beginning of the mapping function, do some kind of blocking check on a globally viewable state (REST-call, maybe?) that only allows some maximum number of checks to succeed at any given time. Since that will delay the full RDD operation, you may need to increase the timeout on RDD finishing to prevent an error

Comment: Still an issue for us and unfortunately the answer appears to be "not possible" with an open, mostly stale issue to make it possible (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20589).

Answer (score 0):

Primary significance of partitioning in spark is for providing parallelism, and your requirement is to reduce parallelism!!! But the the requirement is genuine :)

What is the real problem with less number of partition? Is writing too much data at once is creating problem? If that is the case, you could  breakdown the per partition writing.

Can you put the data in some intermediate queue and process the at a controlled manner?

Comment: The problem with fewer partitions is that each partition becomes larger. Down the Spark pipeline there are operations that are expecting a reasonable number of records per partition and will run out of memory. Your last statement is exactly what I'm looking to get Spark to do.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to enable dynamic allocation, and set the maximum number of executors to your desired maximum parallelism.

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors <maximum>
```

You can read more about configuring dynamic allocation is described here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling

If you are trying to control one specific computation, you could experiment with programmatically controlling the number of executors:

https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-sparkcontext.adoc#dynamic-allocation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that's different from just setting the max cores from the beginning?

Comment: Other apps can use executors that your app is not using.

Comment: If you don't care about the case of other apps, the programmatic control option may work for you.   Kill some executors prior to your RDD job to limit parallelism, then re-start them after it is done.

Comment: Now I understand what you're staying. How would you know when to request more executors in a large pipeline? I can only think of a custom SparkListener. Not quite as clean as I was hoping for.

Comment: Spark's compute model isn't really designed to do what you want.  The only per-RDD parallelism control is the number of partitions.  So any solution to your problem is going to be a hack of some kind.

Comment: I figured as much, but it was worth a shot. Maybe I'll make a feature request and see where that takes me.

Comment: One possibly easier hack:   use a mapPartitions call, and at the beginning of the mapping function, do some kind of blocking check on a globally viewable state (REST-call, maybe?) that only allows some maximum number of checks to succeed at any given time.  Since that will delay the full RDD operation, you may need to increase the timeout on RDD finishing to prevent an error