# Apache Spark - restricting per stage concurrent thread count

Tags: apache-spark

I want to control the number of concurrent partitions being processed at every stage in my Spark RDD. `.repartition(...)` is not the solution, as that just modifies the overall number of partitions during a stage, not how many are being processed.

Normally you restrict the number of concurrent partitions at the start by using the `--executor-cores` and `--num-executors` parameters. And that is not exact, as processing stages can be staggered etc.

The main thing I want to accomplish is a dataload process from a database with certain resource restrictions (concurrent connections) - but I do not want those database resource restrictions to dictate the concurrency of the rest of my spark process or RDD. I also do not want to force very huge partitions at the beginning of the process that will have to be further split and redistributed.

It seems like a reasonable thing to expect, but at first glance not something that can be accomplished within the Spark API.

Example (some pseudo code)

```
rdd = pseudoReadFromJDBC(partitions = 500,parallelism=10)
  .repartition(100)
  .parallelism(50)
  .operatorOnRDD();
```

So in this case, In the first stage, I would split the data retrieved from the JDBC Query in 500 smaller datasets. However, I would restrict Spark from only allowing to run 10 threads of it simultaneously, so I have maximum only 10 JDBC Connections simultaneously opened. Other partitions would just queue up.

Then in the second stage, I might repartition, but more importantly, I want to choose a higher degree of actual parallelism because I am not restricted anymore by the database allowing a limited amount of simultaneous connections.

That is what I mean with changing it on a per stage basis.

Comment: My guess: this is something the "input format" controls, not spark. E.g. the JDBC connector has a numPartitions setting that allows to set the number of concurrent connections (provided there is enough executors to reach it). The elasticsearch input format will match the number of shards. The parquet input format will match the number of input files... The number of splits is something sparks is given, not something it acts upon. (My level on knowledge is limited on the subject, I'm not fully confident this adresses your question).

Comment: The InputFormat, and the numParttitions etc effect the number of shards or partitions - it does not dictate the concurrency. Example, I can set up 1000 partitions, but maybe only 100 partitions will be processed in parallel. Also Parallelism is not just just dictated by the number of executors, but by the number of executor cores * number of executors. This is just the environment it runs in, but I want to narrow that further down during execution.

Comment: @Yoyo did you figure this one out? I've tried to get the same question answered with no success (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492682/limit-max-parallelism-for-a-single-rdd-without-decreasing-the-number-of-partitio)

Comment: I do not have a solution other than decoupling the stages into individually scheduled RDD's, and have a publish/subscribe mechanism or something similar in between.

Answer (score 0):

There is one parameter spark.default.parallelism. You can try changing value of this.

Comment: Which again, just like the other two parameters I have listed, affects the whole Spark Submission, and not just one Stage within your  RDD. Also it only affects the total number of partitions, not the actual parallelism (contrary to what the name suggests).